# Tap Input Emulation Programmatically

Tags: android, eclipse, string, shell, root

I am trying to make my service emulate tap input, but it isn't working.

My main activity already called

```
try {

            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

My service checks if a toggle button is clicked I want to call

```
try {

                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input tap" + Main.xValue.toString() + Main.yValue.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```

But to no success, could someone explain why?

Comment: flagged as off-topic because it's asking for debugging slaves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simulate touch from background service with sendevent or other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928197/how-to-simulate-touch-from-background-service-with-sendevent-or-other-way)

Answer (score 1):

As an example lets say:
`Main.xValue.toString() = 10`
`Main.yValue.toString() = 20`

So according to your code, the line :

```
"input tap" + Main.xValue.toString() + Main.yValue.toString()
```

will be "input tap1020"

but you expect "input tap 10 20" !

try :

```
try {
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c input tap " + Main.xValue.toString() + " " + Main.yValue.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```