# Android touch screen guestures input from another phone

Tags: android, android-source

I am trying to implement a very simple hack.
Suppose there are 2 android phones which are connected via wifi and I run an app in Phone B which sends events to phone A like a pinch / swipe / turn.

So conceptually I would have to write an app which opens a socket and whenever there is an event sends an ioctl to kernel driver which injects these virtual events into android input subsystem

I just dont know what part in android that I need to push virtual events any help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need an rooted device as Phone A, look on this answers:

[How to simulate touch from background service with sendevent or other way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928197/how-to-simulate-touch-from-background-service-with-sendevent-or-other-way)

[How to simulate a touch event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

and:

- [Programmatically Injecting Events on Android – Part 1](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/#.UUu1jzdj8fX)
- [How to compile Android Application with system permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598662/how-to-compile-android-application-with-system-permissions)
- [Instruction for compile here](https://groups.google.com/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-04?_done=/group/Android-DevPhone-Updating/browse_frm/month/2010-04?&&pli=1)