# can android simulate touch screen by x and y?

Tags: android

I'm new in android, I want to touch/click a button in an application(app like facebook or any others, not I developed), and I think it can work by getting the screen event to touch screen by coordinate(x and y), could anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: You mean like UI automation tools?

Comment: @Sunil Yes, but I need to write the code in my app, not use other tool....

Comment: perhaps this ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928197/how-to-simulate-touch-from-background-service-with-sendevent-or-other-way

Comment: It can also be done with Tasker (app) which requires root access.