# Cannot use Input Tap outside of android app

Tags: android, touch

I have read [From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928197/how-to-simulate-touch-from-background-service-with-sendevent-or-other-way) on reply of @Legolas108 on how to do the tap and have success using it inside the app but when i tried it to put into service and do the same for Outside the app, i have been unsuccessful with it.

I can't replicate v1k's comment on how he did it as system App to do the Tap

How can i managed to make The input Tap work outside/another app? or is there any way to replicate this function.

Sorry i am kinda new to this.